# GridView RowEditing event only fires on alternate rows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView as below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvChain" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <Columns>                       
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" ControlStyle-Width="175px">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDepartment" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDepartment" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle Width="175px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manager Level 1" ControlStyle-Width="175px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblManager1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="cbManager1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle Width="175px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manager Level 2" ControlStyle-Width="175px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblManager2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="cbManager2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle Width="175px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="buttonStyle" CausesValidation="false"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="buttonStyle" CausesValidation="false"/>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="buttonStyle" CausesValidation="false" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="buttonStyle" CausesValidation="false" />
                        </ItemTemplate>      
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

The BoundField is populated in the Page_Load event as below:

```
Dim dHandler As DepartmentHandler = New DepartmentHandler
    Dim depts As New List(Of Department)
    depts = dHandler.GetDepartmentList
    gvChain.DataSource = depts.

If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
       gvChain.DataBind()
End If
```

Populating of the TemplateFields is then done in the RowDataBound event as below:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit Then

            Dim cbManager1 As DropDownList = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("cbManager1"), DropDownList)
            Dim cbManager2 As DropDownList = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("cbManager2"), DropDownList)

            Dim eHandler As EmployeeHandler = New EmployeeHandler

            ' Get the list of managers
            Dim mgrs As New List(Of Manager)
            mgrs = eHandler.GetManagerList
            cbManager1.DataSource = mgrs
            cbManager2.DataSource = mgrs
            cbManager1.DataValueField = "Name"
            cbManager1.DataTextField = "Name"
            cbManager2.DataValueField = "Name"
            cbManager2.DataValueField = "Name"
            cbManager1.DataBind()
            cbManager2.DataBind()

            ' Get the department name from the label in cell 0
            Dim lbl As Label = e.Row.Cells(0).FindControl("lblDepartment")
            Dim dept As Department = New Department
            dept.Department = lbl.Text

            ' Pass the department name to the getManager1/2 functions to return the correct manager for that department
            Dim mgr1 As Manager = eHandler.getManager1(dept)
            Dim mgr2 As Manager = eHandler.getManager2(dept)

            ' Upper case the manager name to search the DDLs for item
            Dim mgr1Name As String = mgr1.Name.ToUpper()
            Dim mgr2Name As String = mgr2.Name.ToUpper()

            ' Find the manager in the DDL and select
            cbManager1.SelectedValue = mgr1Name
            cbManager2.SelectedValue = mgr2Name
        Else
            ' If GV isnt in edit mode then populate labels in itemtemplate with manager 1 and 2 values
            Dim lblManager1 As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblManager1"), Label)
            Dim lblManager2 As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblManager2"), Label)


            Dim eHandler As EmployeeHandler = New EmployeeHandler
            Dim lbl As Label = e.Row.Cells(0).FindControl("lblDepartment")
            Dim dept As Department = New Department
            dept.Department = lbl.Text
            Dim mgr1 As Manager = eHandler.getManager1(dept)
            Dim mgr2 As Manager = eHandler.getManager2(dept)

            lblManager1.Text = mgr1.Name
            lblManager2.Text = mgr2.Name
        End If
    End If
```

I then have the below in the RowEditing event

```
gvChain.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
gvChain.DataBind()
```

When there is only 1 record displayed in the GridView, I click the edit button and the GridView goes into Edit mode I am able to update that record using the RowUpdating event and this works fine. However, if I add another record to the GridView, clicking on the edit button of that record gives a NullReference exception. If I then add another record, that 3rd record will go into edit mode. A 4th record will again fail with a NullReference exception and so on.

When debugging, it seems that on rows indexes 1,3,5 etc. the GridView doesn't go into edit mode however on row indexes 0, 2, 4 etc. the GridView will switch to edit mode.

This seems really strange behaviour. Any ideas what may be causing the GridView not to go into Edit mode on these rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got round this by amending the getDepartmentList function to return the Manager1 and Manager 2 fields then databinding them in the same was as I had bound 'Department'.

I then amended the RowDataBound event to the following:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        If e.Row.RowState And DataControlRowState.Edit Then

            Dim cbManager1 As DropDownList = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("cbManager1"), DropDownList)
            Dim cbManager2 As DropDownList = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("cbManager2"), DropDownList)

            Dim eHandler As EmployeeHandler = New EmployeeHandler

            ' Get the list of managers
            Dim mgrs As New List(Of Manager)
            mgrs = eHandler.GetManagerList
            cbManager1.DataSource = mgrs
            cbManager2.DataSource = mgrs
            cbManager1.DataValueField = "Name"
            cbManager1.DataTextField = "Name"
            cbManager2.DataValueField = "Name"
            cbManager2.DataValueField = "Name"
            cbManager1.DataBind()
            cbManager2.DataBind()

            ' Get the department name from the label in cell 0
            Dim lbl As Label = e.Row.Cells(0).FindControl("lblDepartment")
            Dim dept As Department = New Department
            dept.Department = lbl.Text

            ' Pass the department name to the getManager1/2 functions to return the correct manager for that department
            Dim mgr1 As Manager = eHandler.getManager1(dept)
            Dim mgr2 As Manager = eHandler.getManager2(dept)

            ' Upper case the manager name to search the DDLs for item
            Dim mgr1Name As String = mgr1.Name.ToUpper()
            Dim mgr2Name As String = mgr2.Name.ToUpper()

            ' Find the manager in the DDL and select
            cbManager1.SelectedValue = mgr1Name
            cbManager2.SelectedValue = mgr2Name
        End If

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

A row's state can be one or a combination of the DataControlRowState values, so use bitwise operations to determine whether the state of the row includes a DataControlRowState value.
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowstate%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

RowState contains more than one value (`Alternate | Edit` if you check RowState property during edit mode) using bit-logic.

Try

```
 If (e.Row.RowState And DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0 Then
```

Comment: Tried this and unfortunately it still does not work, the GridView is still not entering edit mode when clicking on the edit buttons in row indexes 1, 3, 5 etc.